# Crystal Reports - order of OR statements in record filter affects results

Tags: filter, crystal-reports, report, filtering

I have a report that should pull blood donor result records if the system has flagged the result as unacceptable. The record filter I'm using is below. My issue is that depending on how the OR statement is ordered the results shown on the report differ. As it is now, if I have a donor with no QUAL_TEST results at all then that donor's unacceptable PHYSICAL results do not appear on the report. If I flip the order of the OR statement then donors with unacceptable PHYSICAL results appear but those who have unacceptable QUAL_TEST results but no PHYSICAL tests do not. Are the parenthesis around the OR statement not doing anything?

```
{DONOR_VISIT.VISIT_DATETIME} in {?Visit Start Date} to {?Visit End Date} and 
({DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N" or 
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N")
```

Comment: you need to use `and` not or `{DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N" and 
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N"`

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the report to only pull donors where both a QUAL_TEST and a PHYSICAL result are marked as unacceptable?

Comment: I suppose that was your requirement...correct?

Comment: The report should pull donors who have an "N" in either of those fields, but not necessarily both. They may have perfectly good PHYSICAL results and a bad QUAL_TEST result but they should appear on the report because of that one unacceptable QUAL_TEST result.

Answer (score 0):

As described by you in this case along with negative check you need to make positive check aswell.

Assuming you hav `Y` if results are good try below

```
{DONOR_VISIT.VISIT_DATETIME} in {?Visit Start Date} to {?Visit End Date} and 
(({DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N" and
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N") or
({DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N" and
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "Y") or
({DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "Y" and
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N"))
```

If dont need the record if both results are bad then remove below and keep rest

```
({DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N" and
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N")
```

Answer (score 0):

Better late than Null-ver!

I think the REAL reason for this is because a NULL was encountered in the process.  If One of the fields has a "N" but the other is blank (or NULL) it will fail to do any part of the selection and that record will be ignored.  An easy solution would be to change the way Crystal handles NULL values in the formula to read "Default Values for NULLS" instead of "Exceptions for NULLS", or to write your formula so that NULL records are not breaking your formula.  I believe it would suffice for the non-date part to use something like:

```
(Not IsNull({DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD}) and 
{DONOR_VISIT_QUAL_TEST.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N") or 
(Not IsNull({DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD}) and 
{DONOR_VISIT_PHYSICAL.ACCEPTABLE_VALUE_CD} = "N")
```